# Sum of null and empty values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe that contains both NULL values and empty strings.

As follows (with code for repro)

```
data = {'vals1':  [None, '100','','200'],
        'vals2': ['100', '100','',''],
         'vals3': ['100', None,'100',None],
        'vals4': ['', '','','']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['vals1','vals2','vals3','vals4'])
```

Output:

```
    vals1   vals2   vals3   vals4
0   None    100     100 
1   100     100     None    
2                   100 
3   200             None
```

You'll see there are legit null values (Python treats 'None' as null) but there are also empty strings, denoted by the blanks which are also a legit feature of the dataset.
We can count the nulls by using `df.isnull().sum()`

which gives:

```
    vals1   vals2   vals3   vals4
0   True    False   False   False
1   False   False   True    False
2   False   False   False   False
3   False   False   True    False
```

And I can sum the null values by using `df.isnull().sum()` which gives:

```
   vals1    1
   vals2    0
   vals3    2
   vals4    0
dtype: int64
```

However, I also need a way of accounting for the empty values too, such that the output becomes something like:

```
       Nulls Empty
vals1    1    1
vals2    0    1
vals3    2    1
vals4    0    4
dtype: int64
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do

```
df=pd.concat([df.isnull().sum(),df.eq('').sum()],keys=['Nulls','Empty'],axis=1)
       Nulls  Empty
vals1      1      1
vals2      0      2
vals3      2      0
vals4      0      4
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do the same sum of values equal to the empty string:

```
df.eq('').sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

not all blank values ​​are `''` but can contain more spaces, so I think we can do:

```
df2 = df.replace(r'^\s*$', '', regex=True)
new_df = df2.isnull().sum().to_frame('Nulls').assign(Empty = df2.eq('').sum())
print(new_df)

       Nulls  Empty
vals1      1      1
vals2      0      2
vals3      2      0
vals4      0      4
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a very important consideration but fortunately is not applicable to my scenario.